# Memory leak in run Celery Django, Gevent strategy with Multi Worker

Tags: django, celery

I used celery with rabbitmq in Django. my tasks are io-bound and I used the gevent strategy. I want to run celery tasks on a multi-process (because gevent runs on a single process). but memory grows up for no reason, without doing any tasks. what happened?

this is my celery command:

```
celery multi start 10 -P gevent -c 500 -A my-app -l info -E --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat --pidfile='my-path' --logfile='my-path'
```

my Django celery config:

```
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 100
CELERY_WORKER_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 400
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60 * 60 * 12
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 60 * 60 * 13
```

celery==5.2.7
django==4.1.2

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem:

Celery warns of this on worker startup that running with DEBUG causes a memory leak.
I did change debug mode to False and fixed memory leak.